# Getting Unexpected Token error when inserting records from execute anonymous

Tags: insert, execute-anonymous, unexpectedexception

```
Custom_Object__c co = new Custom_Object__c(Name='TEST', Date_of_Visit__c=2019-06-06);
insert co;
```

Comment: You will need to provide exact code and field details here. If this is what you have then there are quite a few issues here. Your custom object should always end with '__c' and then the way you are populating the date is not correct either, assuming that it’s a date field.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't provided much in the way of details here, but I'd suspect that your issue is with the date you're trying to set to `Date_of_Visit__c`

I know that SOQL queries can handle date literals, but I don't think that the rest of Apex at large can.

You should create an instance of the [Date class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm) using something like `Date.valueOf()`, and set your Date field equal to that instead.

Comment: Also seems the custom object name here is an issue. At least with the level of information provided.